# getAttributeSetId() always error

Tags: magento

I tried to get the attribute_set_id with this code:

```
$SetId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_setup')
         ->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product','Default');
```

However, I always get this error:

```
Call to a member function select() on a non-object in 
magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php on line 734
```

And this is Setup.php line 734:

```
$select = $adapter->select()
          ->from($table)
          ->where($adapter->quoteIdentifier($idField) . '= :id_field');
```

What I know **Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup** class already extends **Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup** class. Why does it still say non-object?

Thank you.

Comment: are you sure adapter is an object? PHP tells you it's not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass constructor argument, as based on it connection adapter is beeing intialized:

```
$SetId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_setup','core_setup')
         ->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product','Default');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `eav/entity_setup` model is aimed to process for sql updates, so it may fail outside that context.

Here is correct snippet:

`Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product', 'Default')`

Comment: I got this error:

    Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Config::getAttributeSetId()